# Como buscar a segunda id de algo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como posso obter acesso a segunda div com o id `general` como tentei no script?

```
<div id="general">ds</div>
<div id="general">ds</div>`

alert($("#general").eq(2).html());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso não é possível *, pois **IDs devem ser únicos**. Se você precisa identificar mais de um elemento com algum nome, use classes em vez de IDs:

```
<div class="general">ds</div>
<div class="general">ds</div>
```

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.general');
alert(divs[0].innerHTML);
alert(divs[1].innerHTML);
```

<sub>* 
Na verdade é possível, como outras respostas e comentários mostram. Mas nunca se deve repetir o ID no HTML, e por isso não pretendo mostrar as gambiarras que permitem selecionar esses elementos com IDs repetidos.</sub>

Comment: é correto mas nao existe 'gambiarra'?

Comment: Talvez se você olhar *todas* as divs do documento e checar o id de cada uma você consiga. Mas eu não recomendaria fazer isso.

Comment: @user3163662 [dê uma olhada aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/8mddnz4s/) e aprenda **como não fazer**. Não use, sério. Corrija o HTML.

Comment: Eu alterei meu HTML porém agora me venho com outra duvida para solucionar esta. Como posso encontrar uma div que contenha um parametro `eq=general` dentro dela? Assim... `<div eq="general"></div>` @Sergio @bfavaretto

Comment: @user3163662 Só que esse é um atributo inválido, ok? Eu usaria `<div data-eq="general">` (atributos com o prefixo `data-` são válidos em HTML5).